# Импорт данных из csv в sql python

Tags: python, sql, pyqt5, pandas, csv

Я импортирую данные из excel таблицы products.xsxl с помощью pandas в csv, теперь из csv мне надо загрузить их в БД pkf с таблицей pkf. Проблема в том, что таблица в БД уже есть, мне не надо создавать новую, однако с помощью pandas, как я поняла, так сделать нельзя. Мне надо именно загрузить данные в уже имеющуюся таблицу с названными столбцами(name, p, k, f), где должны лежать названия продуктов и их белки, жиры, углеводы, которые лежат в products (без названий столбцов). Впоследствии эта таблица должна будет обновляться, поэтому мне нельзя ее пересоздавать, надо именно добавлять данные. Можно ли это как-то сделать? Если что, я использую pyqt5

```
        read_file = pd.read_excel("products.xsxl")
        read_file.to_csv("pkf.csv",
                         index=None,
                         header=True)
        df = pd.read_csv("pkf.csv")
        con = sqlite3.connect("pkf.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        df.to_sql("pkf", con, if_exists='append', index=False)
        con.commit()
```

Comment: https://python.ivan-shamaev.ru/python3-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-write-data-in-table/ Здесь всё описано по параметрам

Comment: @Виктор я все делала по этой документации, все вроде указано, но как-то не особо работать хочет

Comment: А у Вас csv с именами столбцов?

Comment: @Виктор нет, там только строки типа "рыба,20,7,14". После обработки в столбце name должна оказаться рыба, в столбце p должно быть число 20 и т.д.

Comment: тогда так читать df = pd.read_csv('pkf.csv', header=None)

Comment: Ещё ошибки какие-нибудь выдаёт?

Comment: @Виктор спасибо, но все равно ничего в БД не поменялось:( я правда даже не представляю в чем проблема, у меня все падает с ошибкой и даже ее я посмотреть не могу, потому что это ошибка формы pyqt5. если вдруг вы найдете еще у меня ошибку в предоставленном коде, буду очень благодарна!

Comment: df.columns =['name', 'p', 'k', 'f'] - добавить перед записью в базу

Comment: Извлеките кусок кода этот в другой файл и с ним из консоли работайте - все ошибки увидите

Comment: @Виктор оно работает!! просто ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо!!!

Comment: Удалите cur = con.cursor() - здесь не нужен